# Hello, On a node.js project, and I cannot move files to a src folder because I got an error when running the node file. Now the files are in the root

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, modularization

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/alejandraola/Documents/GitHub/SCL16-md-link/prueba.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

I expected to be able to. move the files to an src folder and run the files from there.

Comment: The question is unclear for me. How do you move the files? It looks like you are trying to import `'/Users/alejandraolea/Documents/GitHub/SCL016-md-link/prueba.js'` but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that node cannot find the module any more after it moved

I think you are importing these files somewhere inside your code,

you need to find this and change it to the new directory,

it will be something similar to this :

```
require("/prueba.js");
```

If you moved it to Src folder then add this to the path as well

```
require("/src/prueba.js");
```